# What steps should I follow to get postgresql into development in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm learning Rails and my final app will be hosted on Heroku, which uses postgres, so I figured it'd be smart to work with postgres in development too as I'm building what is supposed to be a rather simple search function and want to avoid as many problems as possible actually deploying it.

Sadly, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 so naturally the steps will be harder than on for example Windows.

Here's what I've done so far, which is a rather comical enterprise into a world that gives me nothing but problems at every step:

1. Actually installed postgresql. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4` as per the official website of course didn't work so I had to find a workaround (as always) but it should be installed now. I ran `sudo apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib` to get it working.
2. Tried logging in per some instructions with `su postgres`, but even after setting a password for su or using `sudo su postgres` that didn't work. Ended up creating a user with `sudo -u postgres createuser -P my_user` matching the name of my app. Created a database too.
3. Tried creating a new rails project with `rails new my_app --database=postgresql`. Didn't work as it complained lacking a pg gem (sorry for not pre-emptively making a Gemfile for you?) so I gave that up and just created it without specifying a database.
4. Removed the sqlite gem and added `gem 'pg'` in the Gemfile. Ran `bundle install`, but it didn't work. Had to run `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` to install something I'm not sure what it is and then it worked.
5. Modified the database.yml as per some instructions and ran `rake db:setup`. Rails gave this error: `FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_user"`. Well, that's cool.
6. Not quite sure why, but I added a database here called `my_app_development` for it with the owner `my_user` but then db:setup instead complained that it lacked permissions to create a database (but I just created it FOR you?).
7. I ran `chmod -R 0666 my_app` as someone highly upvoted on SO suggested but holy shit that was bad as it didn't even give me permissions to enter the folder myself! Reverted that quickly and tried something else.
8. Someone suggested running `psql -U my_user postgres` but that only gives me the error `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_user"`
9. Experimented logging in via `psql postgres` (I don't know what psql is, I'm just following suggestions) and tried `ALTER ROLE my_user CREATEDB;` but it only returns a permission denied error.
10. Officially gave up and came here.

**Can anyone help me with the actual steps to follow from the beginning?** It shouldn't be THIS hard, right?

By the way, this is what my database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: my_user
  password: my_password

test:
  <<: *default
 database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

**Edit:** Thanks alot to Ajay for walking me through how to setup postgres. If anyone comes across this thread, as frustrated as I am with postgres, here are a few pointers:

- `PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create database` means the user doesn't have the right privileges. Log in via `sudo -u postgres psql` and you should see `postgres=#` before everything you type in the terminal. While there, type `ALTER ROLE my_user CREATEDB;` and it should work. I don't know why it didn't the first time I used that, perhaps I forgot sudo?
- `FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "my_user"` means you need to change some things in a file as per the instructions in one of the answers. Make sure to change it for both local and postgres. I have it set to `md5` for everything but local and it works.
- Login via `sudo -u postgres psql` and type `select * from pg_catalog.pg_user;' to check your current users. Good way to see if you created the user correctly and what privileges it has.

Comment: Advice: If you want to use PostgreSQL as your production database, forget about any other database: All databases are different, you will find issues in production that you didn't have in your development environment. Search for sqlite and change it to postgresql

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing?

Comment: the `host: localhost` in your `database.yml` is all you need to fix the "Peer authentication" error you mention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **5.** Modified the database.yml as per some instructions and ran rake
>   db:setup. Rails gave this error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed
>   for user "my_user". Well, that's cool.

you need to open your **pg_hba.conf** (probally located at `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`) and change the authentication method from "**peer**" to "**md5**" (which will asks for password) or to "trust" (which will unsecuritly allow access without password).

To know where your pg_hba is located, execute this on your terminal (terminal of the machine where the postgresql are running):

```
ps ax | grep postgresql.conf
```

it should return something like:

```
8803 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

look the folder where `config_file` is located. In this case is `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/`. Inside this folder there's another configuration file called pg_hba.conf (the permissions file). Edit it (with super user):

`sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`

on the lasts lines you will see something like that:

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

You see the "trust" references? In your default pg_hba.conf they should be "peer". In my example, I had changed to "trust" (i.e, doesn't ask for passwords) all local connections, because my postgresql server not accept outside connections. But you can change to "md5", which will permit access when the user provide the correct password.

After change this, save and exit (in nano is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit). Then, restart postgresql (`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` - maybe works with just a reload)

---

**UPDATE:**

**DISCLAIMER:**

although trusting your local connections will not create a hole security (unless, of course you are sharing the machine with anothers users), do it only for testing purposes - to discover where the problem is (if is a permission/pg_hba problem or not). After discover where the problem are, its more concise to have one specific user to your project and use an authentication for it ("md5", "peer").

Using one single user for all your projects on the machine (e.g. the "postgres" user), and/or not use an authentication ("trust"), is like create a Rails project and use just one generic controller, instead having a controller for each table/group of logic.

Comment: don't do this, you really don't need to -_-

Comment: hi @sevenseacat, I don't think its a bad thing to trust your local connections, unless you are sharing the machine with another users. Its bad from the "beauty" point, but not from the security point (unless I'm missing something here). Its more concise if you create an user specifically to your database/project, but for testing purposes, to see where is the problem, I think is a valid point to trust all connections. But again, this is what I *think*, I would like to see your point - not to argument (like a fight), but to broaden my thoughts.

Comment: I do an update ("disclaimer"). I hope this has become better :)

Answer (score 3):

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Above `adapter: sqlite3` is causing the error

Please try this:

```
default: &default
 adapter:  postgresql
 pool:    5
 timeout: 5000 

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
  username: psql #postgres username
  password: your_password #password
```

After you entered the valid postgres credentials(username/password) here. Try following in your terminal :

```
 $ rake db:create #this will create your my_app_development database. 
 $ rake db:migrate #migrate your database.
```

Comment: `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_user"`. I've started running `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:setup` now by the way to avoid those kind of problems.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson, Sir please try to login to postgres with your my_user/password first.  sudo -u postgres my_user . Based on userrole created in postgres, you can modify above configuration.

Comment: Then technically you don't have 'my_user' user created in your postgres. If you have done the standard configurations then the default user is psql.
Please try sudo -u postgres psql

Comment: Yeah, that worked with the password I created earlier. I've entered here before. Not sure what psql is. What am I supposed to do here now?

Comment: Great then ! So, here psql is your username & you know the password. Hence use those credentials in the database.yml file -> development block.
Just updated my answer again, you can check.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "psql"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however I feel the other answer at least as it stands now is more suitable as the best answer should someone stumble across this thread searching for help.

Comment: I understand @LyndonJohnson :) I am glad, someway your issue got fixed :)